# name web service for biological taxons?

Tags: ajax, autocomplete

Once I found a name web service for biological taxons in the Internet(forgot to bookmark it) and  cannot find it anymore. I am very sad and obfuscated! If anyone knows about it, please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Without being more specific, the only thing that might server as a starting point might be  http://www.ebi.ac.uk/services ( ? )

Comment: The name web service that I saw was about species (animals vegetals, etc )